# Some specific block on a wordpress page should not be cached from varnish

Tags: wordpress, varnish

I'm using varnish 3.0 for this website http://beautyqa.nykaa.com/. if you will open this link http://beautyqa.nykaa.com/how-does-the-freedom-to-use-makeup-feel/ here, below title of the article you will find some post-meta-information like "**August 7, 2015 | Posted by Madhavi Irani | BeautyBookSTYLE ALERT | 2 comments | 329 views**". This much information should not be cached from varnish because number of views need to be increase on each page load. In `single.php` I'm calling a function `post_meta_details()` which is returning the same information.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a [good answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/485884/varnish-exclude-section-of-page) on stackoverflow.
You are looking for [ESIfeatures](https://web.archive.org/web/20171210030815/http://varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ESIfeatures)

Unfortunately this is not easy to integrate into wordpress.

I recommend too look for a plugin which delivers the amount of comments and views via ajax. So it would be able to bypass the varnish cache.

Keep in mind that you have to exclude the wp-ajax.php route from caching with varnish than.